# Where's telegram saving files when launched from Rambox?

Tags: ubuntu, telegram-messenger

I've downloaded a file in Telegram but I can't find it in my disk. I'm running Telegram through Rambox in Ubuntu. The files is a .pdf one

After ending the download, I could see this dialogue and I'm thinking that it's not able to download because it doesn't know how to manage the file.
[image]

Do you know where files are stored after being downloaded and how to select a different folder if possible?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found that when I download a file where Rambox doesn't know how to manage, them are not automatically downloaded, and the system does nothing.

So, if this is also your case, you have to right click on the file icon you want to download and click on download, instead of clicking on the arrow to download.

Don't click here...

[image: Don't click on here]

Right click on the file and select download. The system will ask you for a destination.

[image: Click on here after right click on the file]

If you just click on the arrow, the system will ask you for an app to manage it and it will not be downloaded. You will need to right click again on the file and after in download.